# Google Api Tasks Client Library for windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client, google-tasks-api

Where i can find sourse code for this google tasks api? Or dll for windows phone 8.1?
[Nuget link for this library: google api tasks v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Tasks.v1/)

This library doesn't support windows phone 8.1 (i need it for wp8.1 winrt core, it platform like supported windows 8.1), but i need this library.

And i don't know when they add support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the code works if i add google library for windows 8.1, I think with the exception of the authorization. Authentication i found here [nokia.develop](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Authentication_Using_Facebook,_Google_and_Microsoft_Account_in_Universal_Apps_Using_MVVM).

Answer (score 1):

Denis, I think you already know that, but I want other users to notice that as well...
[signed google.apis.dll is giving compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689496/signed-google-apis-dll-is-giving-compiler-error)

All sources are available at - https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/download/library/[API_NAME]/[API_VERSION]/csharp, so the tasks source can be downloaded from:
https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/download/library/tasks/v1/csharp