# signed google.apis.dll is giving compiler error

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I got the source code for the latest Google.Apis, Google.Apis.Core and Google.Apis.Auth.dll (all 1.9.x.x) and compiled them with strong name. Now when I compile my code using the strong named dlls it gives an error:

---

```
The type 'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.9.0.23042, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

---

in the line: `UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(flow, "me", token);`

Everything works just fine without strong name. I need to add the strong name because my main program where this library is referred has strong name.

Any ideas?

Comment: okay I got some clue, if I remove the code related to Google.Apis.Plus.v1 and Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 then the code compiles. Even though I add strong key to these dlls, they are causing some issue. Can someone tell me where to find the dotnet sources for these dll so that I can recompile the sources using strong key. I searched in google code repository, but they seemed to be generated using some tool.

Comment: Update: The file Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.cs that I downloaded from code.google.com seems to be created for .net framework 2.0 and so it is old. Any ideas where google put the new files or how can we generate one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources for Google APIs Calendar, Drive, Youtube and all are available at: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/download/library/[API_NAME]/[API_VERSION]/csharp.

For example to download the latest Calendar API source, use the following link -  https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/download/library/calendar/v3/csharp

Comment: This is what I needed! I did decompile the libraries yesterday and could do the compilation with strong key again but having it from the source helps.

I think giving a strong-key version of these libraries will also help, especially when it gives error if you sign the existing dlls.

Comment: I have been looking for those links for a year or more.